# I am having difficulty understanding pointer

Tags: c++, pointers

I was experimenting some pointer exercises.
at the end of the code when a=b, I tried to print value and address of p pointing to, which should be - address of a & the second 2.but the result is blank. What can be the problem ?

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    cout << "Hello World" << endl;

    int * p;
    *p = 22;
    //p=9;

    int a =1;
    int b = 2;

    //p = &a;

    //*p = 24;

    cout << p << " Pointer with no address to" << endl;
    cout << *p << endl;

    //pointer p saves the address of a in p
    p=&a;


    //should show the address of a
    cout << p << " Pointer with address to a" << endl;
    //should show the value of a
    cout << *p << endl;

    a=b;


    cout << p << endl;
    cout << *p ;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your problems start with `int * p;
*p = 22;`

Comment: A pointer must point to an object before it can be de-referenced. You are de-referencing `p` before it points to anything.

Comment: Maybe you mean `int x = 0; int *p; p = &x; ... *p = 22;`? Also, when you say this **Pointer with no address to**, then the next line `*p` is undefined behavior.

Comment: think of each variable to have a name and an address. the address is basically just a number, referring to one particular memory-slot. A pointer, is a variable that hold that address as its **value**. pointers therefore point to other variables. by dereferencing the pointer, you access that other variable

Comment: @chris, the code works even when i put value of pointer p as 22, if i comment the last 3 lines of code,

Comment: @Wang'lPakhrin, Appearing to work does not mean it's working. Undefined behaviour can work sometimes and then break later on with no problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`*p = 22` does *not* make `p` point to the number `22`.

To do that, you need to first initialize that value `22` somewhere:

```
int i = 22;
```

And then you can make `p` point to `i`:

```
p = &i;
```

Comment: is it necessary to do that ? even if i don't , it still takes in value 22 ?

Comment: @Wang'lPakhrin The point is that the value has to be stored *somewhere* before anything can point to it. The pointer cannot just start pointing to a value that doesn't exist.

Comment: thanks for the tip ! So a pointer should be addressed first and then dereferenced to call the value to the pointer pointing towards.

Comment: Exactly. Never dereference a pointer that's not pointing to an actual value.

Answer (score 0):

Take the `*p = 22` away, uncomment the first `p=&a` (delete the second), and it should run as normal.

---

BTW, think about what a pointer *is* - it points to another value by means of the second value's memory address.

so, `*p = 22` doesn't mean anything, without the pointer having a memory address to mess with. (You may want to initialize it as a null pointer - `int *p = NULL`)

Once `p=&a`, that means the variable `p` holds the memory address of `a`. You don't need to re-assign it every time you change `a`. No matter the value in it, you can from then on access it by `*p`.

Comment: though it does not mean anything, *p takes in value 22 , before being de-referenced, beacuse when i omit the last 3 lines of code starting a=b, the code works.